# Batch file does not run after upgrading to W10

Tags: windows, batch-file, command

I had recently upgrade from W7 to W10 and everything seems to work but this basic batch command. Whenever I launch the file, the cmd keeps outputting *"The system cannot accept the date entered"*

There were no modifications to my knowledge, but perhaps there were some shifting files that happened during the upgrade, I'm not so sure.

So essentially, I need to have the batch file modify the current date since the application in question does not open correctly with the current date and reverting back to the current date a few seconds after the batch executes.

This is the batch file:

```
set curdate=%date%
date %date:~0,-4%2014
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\HK-Software\IBExpert"
start ibexpert.exe
@TIMEOUT /NOBREAK /T 10
date %curdate%
```

Comment: check if your date format is still the same.

Comment: Tell us what is output on the screen when you enter **`ECHO(%DATE%`** into the CMD window prompt.

Comment: Hi, The date format is still the same and has not been modified. The date displayed using echo in cmd is 02/08/17

Comment: Good, now enter this, **`ECHO(%DATE:~0,-4%`** into the CMD window prompt and tell us the output.

Comment: Interesting: _"The date format is still the same"_, but previously the year was displayed in 4 digits and now in just 2...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the code in that script is not compatible with the **`%DATE%`** your machine is outputting.

The following offers a quick fix as long as your machine also accepts the two digit year when setting `date`.

```bat
set curdate=%date%
date %date:~0,-2%14
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\HK-Software\IBExpert"
start ibexpert.exe
TIMEOUT /NOBREAK /T 10
date %curdate%
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Just a small little change with the clock and it worked. I appreciate the help from everyone!